# Salesforce forcasts: Adjusted Total Not appearing for some users

Tags: opportunity, forecast

While viewing opportunity forecasts, some users do not have the 'Adjusted Total' as highlighted in the picture.

The Adjusted total enable users to have a detailed view of their opportunities.

Is there a configuration that I have missed?

Note we already have forecast enabled on users and users assigned in the forecast hierarchy.

Thanks
Nawshine[image]